# Help with zsh: command not found

Tags: zsh, path, command-not-found, bitcoin

Attempting to [follow these instructions](https://docs.ordinals.com/guides/inscriptions.html) and I'm receiving error `zsh: command not found: ord` when attempting to do anything in `ord`, including `ord wallet create`. Currently running ohmyzsh and have not altered the .zshrc file.

When I use echo $PATH, I receive `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

I'm new to this, so my apologies if the answer is obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: terminal window]

[image: top of .zshrc file]

Comment: The installer seems to install in `~/bin` by default, so you'd need a `path+=(~/bin)`

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)